# Will the Session() close after terminate the python script?

Tags: python, session, python-requests, urllib2

I've written a simple python code to login to a forum, in order to keep alive and gain the online time. The code is as following:

```
logPara = {'username':user,'password':pwd}
s = requests.Session()
s.post(forumUrl,data=logPara)
homePage = requests.get(pageUrl)
```

I can get the correct homePage and am sure the login is successful. While I'm curious how long will this Session() last? If my program only contains theses four lines, will the Session() close thus the online status is lost?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely the session will be lost. 
So, you two options for making the session last longer, One is as the answer posted by @Seekheart. Second is to save the session state in a file using python's pickle and load it again when needed. But this also will depend on the cookie expiration etc.

This is how you can do it. 
When making the session request:

```
import pickle    
import requests

logPara = {'username':user,'password':pwd}
s = requests.Session()
s.post(forumUrl,data=logPara)
homePage = requests.get(pageUrl)

with open('temp.dat', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(s, f)
```

When you want to get the state back later:

```
import pickle

with open('temp.dat', 'r') as f:
    s = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: I understand your point and thx for the quick reply @Seekheart. While, another question is, when the session is closed, will it hit the "log out" event? The online status will keep about 10 mins so my program is run by Cron every 5 minutes. While it seems when the script is over, "log out" is triggered.

Comment: Log out could no be triggered by the script, but when you start a new session previous state (cookies) are lost, which are required by the server to keep you logged in.

Comment: Do you mean the server will periodically request the cookie from the client (browser, or python API)?     Another question is, is it okay to use multiple session objects in one script? s1 = requests.Session()     s2 = requests.Session()     will s1 be overwritten by s2? thx

Comment: Server wont request the cookie, but when you send any http get or post request to the server, the cookie needs to be sent alongwith the request so that the server can identify that the client is logged in. Yes it is perfectly fine two instantiate two different objects of same class. Those wont interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the script, unless the script is being told to run endlessly or after a certain condition, it'll terminate almost immediately. So for your script it'll end after you run it. To continue running it you can put in a condition like for example.

```
while 1:
     #Run your code
```